# Find solutions of $(x-y)^n=xy$ over naturals excluding $0$.

Tags: number-theory

Find solutions of $(x-y)^n=xy$ over naturals excluding $0$.

**My attempt**:I proved that If there is a solution we should have $n=3$.It is easy to do that we just have to take $gcd(x,y)=d,x=da,y=db,gcd(a,b)=1$ then by simplifying we get $a=r^{n-2},b=s^{n-2},gcd(r,s)=1,rs=d$ and we get $r^{n-2}-s^{n-2}=1$ so $n \le 3$ we can easily check the cases $n=1,2$ and see there are no solutions.But I think we have infinity solutions in acse $n=3$ because we can take $a=b+1$ and $ab=r$ for example $a=4,b=3,d=12$ but [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-y)%5E3%3Dxy%20over%20integers) gives only one solution and that is $x=4,y=2$ but why?I've already found another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are infinitely many positive integer solutions with $x = b(b+1)^2, y = b^2 (b+1), n=3$.  To be fair, I don't think Wolfram Alpha actually claims to find all solutions.